# Start Stop Kestrel server(Asp.Net Core) from WPF button

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to follow this : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft

I understand registering the IWebHost for the Application Stopping method, but how to make a call to gracefully shutdown kestrel?
May be it's probably a silly question! But I am unable to find a way.

**Code: [Startup.cs]**

```
    public IWebHost host = null;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IWebHost host)
    {
        this.host = host;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);

            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

public void OnShutdown()
        {
            //cleaning the resources
        }
```

**Code [Init file]**

```
 System.Threading.CancellationToken ct;
 port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTTP_Port"]);
                 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseUrls($"https://localhost:{port}/")
                        .Build();
                host.Run(ct);
```

How to stop the server programmatically?

Comment: http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/looking-at-asp-net-cores-iapplicationlifetime#disqus_thread